# write sql results to XML using python

Tags: python, xml, sql-server-2005

using SQL server 2005+

for over a year now, I've been running a query to return all users from the database for whom i'd like generate a report for. at the end of the query, I've added

> for xml auto

The result of this is a link to a file where the xml lives (one row, one column). I then take this file and pass it through some xslt and am left with the final xml that a java program I created nearly two years ago can parse.

What i'd like to do is skip the whole middle part and simply automate this all with python.
Run the query, put the results into xml format and then either use the xslt or simply format the xml that's returned into the format that I need for the application.

I've searched far and wide on the internet but I'm afraid I'm not sure enough of the technologies available to find just what I'm looking for.

Any help in directing me to an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this. If what you have works, then why change it?

Comment: what i have works, but i'd like to AUTOMATE what I have.  each of the steps i enumerate above is done manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyODBC](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) to talk to MS SQL Server, [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html) to handle the XSLT, and [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to run your Java program.

Comment: will give this a shot shortly. Thanks for all your help today Ignacio.